# Django no reverse match at

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my code I'm trying to create an edit button to modify the employees subsequently displayed and make the changes but I can't display with dynamic url in django.

**views.py**

```
def editerEmploye(request, pk):
editer = Employe.objects.get(id=pk)

context = {'editer':editer}
return render(request, 'accounts/editer_form.html', context)
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home),
path('dashboard/', views.home, name="dashboard"),
path('employe/', views.employe, name="employe"),
path('disciplinaire/', views.disciplinaire, name="disciplinaire"),
path('employe_form/', views.createEmploye, name="employe_form"),
path('editer_form/<str:pk>/', views.editerEmploye, name="editer_form"),
```

**employe.html**

```
<td><a href="{% url 'editer_form' employe.id %}">Editer </a>
```

**models.py**

```
class Employe(models.Model):
Matricule = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Nom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
Adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Courriel = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Horaire = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Date_embauche = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

[screenShot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M6Ay.png)

Comment: Can you share full template or necessary part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'editer_form' employe.id %}">Editer </a>
```

You don't have `employe` in the context. You need to change it to:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'editer_form' editer.id %}">Editer </a>
```

And you should change `<str:pk>` to `<int:pk>` if it is `id`.